# SDTT says "Unspecified Type" for 'name' in <link>

Tags: html, schema.org, rdfa

My code:

```html
<main vocab="http://schema.org"> 
<article  typeof="NewsArticle">

<h2 property="headline">Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10</h2>

 <link property="image" href="http://htmlkurss.xyz/Bilder/Virtualbox.png" />

  <meta property="name" content="Virtual Box" />
  <meta property="mainEntityOfPage" content="http://google.de" />
  <meta property="datePublished" content="2019-03-07" />
  <meta property="dateModified" content="2019-03-17" />
  <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
    <link property="name" href="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
     <span property="logo" typeof="ImageObject">
      <link property="contentUrl url" href="http://htmlkurss.xyz/Bilder/Virtualbox.png"  title="VirtualBox"/>
   </span>
   </span>

  <div property="text">Virtual Box ist eine Virtualisierungssoftware, die viele Betriebessysteme emulieren kann. Sie funktioniert mit Linux , Mac und Windows. Sie hat auch veschiedenene Sprachen für ihre Oberfläche, wie beispielsweise Deutsch, Englisch ,... 
  </div>

 <span property="author" typeof="Person" >
  <meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
  </span>

</article>
```

**Google Structured Data Testing Tool** says that all is good, except this piece:

```html
<span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
    <link property="name" href="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
```

For `name`, it says:

> Not selected Type

[image]

but when I use `meta`, it doesn’t give this warning:

```
 <span property="publisher" typeof="Organization">
    <meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
```

But I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466028/how-to-implement-mainentityofpage-to-this-specific-site) the best solution when giving an URL is to use `<link>` and `href=""`.

What can I do to prevent the "Unspecified Type" warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, "Unspecified Type" is not a warning. The SDTT simply states that no type is specified.

Why does it do this?

Because you are providing a URL value for a [property](https://schema.org/name) which expects a Text value:

> **Values expected to be one of these types**
>   `Text`

It doesn’t make much sense to say that the `name` is represented/identified by a URL. If your `Organization` really has the name "http://htmlkurss.xyz" (instead of "HTML Kurss", for example), then you should still use the `meta` element, because it’s not a URL, it’s a string that looks like a URL.

```html
<meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
```

For the actual URL of the `Organization`, you would use:

```html
<link property="url" href="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />
```

Comment: Very Thanks for your explanation , i understand it ! , i will write "<meta property="name" content="http://htmlkurss.xyz" />"